# Regex Negative Look Ahead

Tags: regex

I have this:

```
172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?!:|_)
```

to match a `172` IP address that is NOT followed by a `:` or `_`

When applied to `172.22.22.22:` it matches on `172.22.22.2` when I wanted no match to occur.
When I do something like `cat(?!:|_)`, the string `cat_` returns no matches.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [*possessive quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) to prevent it from backing up.

```
172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}+(?!:|_)
                              ^
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iI1kU9)

Answer (score 0):

Escape **dots** and then check for the end of string:

```
172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?!:|_)$
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aD7xN3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?![\d:_])
```

i.e. make sure negative lookahead is matching colon or underscore after all digits only.

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qP3tK9)